# python: create 2 com objects

Tags: python-2.7, dispatch

I need to connect remotely to two instruments using win32com, but I get an error when the second object is created. the code looks like this:

```
scope1 = win32com.client.Dispatch("LeCroy.ActiveDSOCtrl.1")  #creates first instance of the ActiveDSO control   
scope1.MakeConnection("GPIB:5") #Connects to device via GPIB

scope2 = win32com.client.Dispatch("LeCroy.ActiveDSOCtrl.2")  #creates a second instance of the ActiveDSO control   
scope2.MakeConnection("IP:127.0.0.1") #Connects to the oscilloscope on local host
```

I get an error at the second COM object creation.
Does anyone know how to make this work if it's possible at all?

Answer (score 0):

For the benefit of others who are remote controlling instruments, the solution is simpler than expected:
scope1 = win32com.client.Dispatch("LeCroy.ActiveDSOCtrl.1")  #creates first instance of the ActiveDSO control

scope1.MakeConnection("GPIB:5") #Connects to device via GPIB
scope2 = win32com.client.Dispatch("LeCroy.ActiveDSOCtrl.1")  #creates the second instance of the ActiveDSO control
scope2.MakeConnection("IP:127.0.0.1") #Connects to the oscilloscope on local host or any other IP address

I can actually create as many activEx object I want, as long as I keep using the same reference in dispatch:  "LeCroy.ActiveDSOCtrl.1"

generator = win32com.client.Dispatch("LeCroy.ActiveDSOCtrl.1")

multimeter= win32com.client.Dispatch("LeCroy.ActiveDSOCtrl.1")
.
.

my mistake was to use .2 which has no reference.